# Set an environment variable containing a sequence of multiple spaces

Tags: shell

I'm solving an exploit challenge where I need to set an environment variable (named EGG) with a string value that contains a sequence of **MULTIPLE SPACES**.
It's OK with strings with single spaces (eg. "`single spaces string example`") but I couldn't find the way to do with multiple spaces (eg. "`multiple     spaces   string                 example`").
Please help!

Comment: Setting a variable with multiple space is not a problem. Just make sure to use double quotes when you echo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ text="multiple     spaces   string                 example"
$ echo $text
multiple spaces string example
$ echo "$text"
multiple     spaces   string                 example
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You made me understand that my problem was not to use double quotes when printing out the environment variable.

Comment: @Vova ... it's not just when printing out the environment variable, but any time you use it, e.g.,    `copy="$text"`